# Hafrashat Challah - Source & Reason

Tags: sources-mekorot, separating-challah

What is the source of this practice?
 Is it a Minhag or Halacha? 
What are the reasons it must be burnt?

Comment: https://www.star-k.org/articles/articles/1197/when-you-need-to-knead-a-guide-to-hafrashas-challah/ https://www.joyofkosher.com/blogs/what-is-hafrashat-challah-separating-the-challah/ https://oukosher.org/blog/consumer-kosher/halachos-of-hafrashas-challah/ https://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Challah

Comment: There is a masechet Chala in Seder zerayim, 4 chapters. Very interesting. You can find Mishna in English in sefaria. מלאך ודמעך לא תאחר

Comment: Did you try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taking_of_Challah ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a Halacha well documented in the written Torah, the Mishna and the Jerusalem-Talmud and then codified by all Poskim.

Torah: [Bamidbar 15:20](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Numbers.15.20?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> ראשית ערסתכם חלה תרימו תרומה כתרומת גרן כן תרימו אתה
>
> As the first yield of your baking, you shall set aside a loaf as a gift; you shall set it aside as a gift like the gift from the threshing floor.

Mishna: [Masechet Challa](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Challah.1?lang=bi)

Talmud Yerushalmi: [Mas. Challa](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Jerusalem_Talmud_Hallah.1a?lang=bi)

Rambam: [Ch. 5 of Hil. Bikurim etc.](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_First_Fruits_and_other_Gifts_to_Priests_Outside_the_Sanctuary.5.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

Shulchan Aruch Yoreh De'ah [section 322 - 330](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.322?lang=bi)

That said, nowadays it may possibly be Rabbinic under certain circumstances.